# Prove uniform convergence of Fourier Series of $2\pi$ periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function that is almost everywhere differentiable. (The derivative is a regulated function.) Show that the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly  on $\mathbb{R}$.

I do not know how I could prove this as the conditions on $f$ are really weak. Could you help me?

Comment: I doubt if it's true.  Any function with a discontinuity won't converge uniformly at that discontinuity - Gibbs phenomenon.  You need continuity as a necessary condition.

Comment: You mean I should assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough to comment on differentiabillty.  However (as I already mentioned) continuity is necessary. Look at:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Uniform_convergence Reference says absolute continuity is sufficient to insure uniform convergence.